# How to retrieve data from SQLite and display in TextView only one at a time when clicked on button

Tags: android, xml, sqlite

I have stored data in SQLite. I need to retrieve data from SQLite and it should display on text view when click on button. And when I again click on button it should get other text view and should show in text view.

Using this code I can display the text view. When I click on the button it is displaying every thing from SQLite, but I need only one text view at a time.

```
public void display(View v)
   {
   //use cursor to keep all data
   //cursor can keep data of any data type
   Cursor c=db.rawQuery("select * from mytable", null);
   tv.setText("");
   if(c!=null && c.getCount()>0)
   {

   //move cursor to first position
   c.moveToFirst();
   //fetch all data one by one
   do
   {
    //we can use c.getString(0) here
    //or we can get data using column index
    String name=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
    String surname=c.getString(1);
    //display on text view
    tv.append(name+surname+"\n");
    //move next position until end of the data
   }while(c.moveToNext());
  }
}
```

Comment: what is meant by only one textview. or you want to display in `ListView` or ?

Comment: i got answer to that.thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your code like below

```
    Cursor c = null;
    public void display(View v)
   {
  //use cursor to keep all data
  //cursor can keep data of any data type
  if(c == null) {
  c=db.rawQuery("select * from mytable", null);
  //move cursor to first position
  c.moveToFirst();
  }

   tv.setText("");
  if(c!=null && c.getCount()>0 && !c.isAfterLast())
 {
//we can use c.getString(0) here
//or we can get data using column index
String name=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
String surname=c.getString(1);
//display on text view
tv.setText(name+surname+"\n");
c.moveToNext();
}
}
```

Comment: i need a code.when i press other button it should go back to previous text view.please help me.

Comment: Cursor cb=null;
     public void back(View v)
    {
   //use cursor to keep all data
   //cursor can keep data of any data type
   if(cb == null) {
   cb=db.rawQuery("select * from mytable", null);
   //move cursor to first position
   cb.moveToPrevious();
   }

    tv.setText("");
   if(cb!=null && cb.getCount()>0 && c.moveToPrevious())
  {
 //we can use c.getString(0) here
 //or we can get data using column index
 String name=cb.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
 String surname=cb.getString(1);
 //display on text view
 tv.setText(name+surname+"\n");

Comment: i am getting error when i write this code.when i press button it is not moving to previous text view.